# How to Create Custom Function for DevExpress XtraReports Calculated Field

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport, calculated-field, custom-formatting

I know how to create Custom Fields in a DataSet for a Report in DecExpress XtraReports.
But I need to Declare a Custom Function in available function list for Calculated Fields. I do not know how to solve this problem.

```
source type : Date
result : Date String In other Calendar Formats

source type : TinyInt (Enumeration)
result : Custom Enumeration Value Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Q232469](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q232469.aspx) and [S132091](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S132091.aspx) it isn't supported without using Scripts. However in saying that the Expression Editor does allow for Custom Functions as per [Implementing Custom Functions](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument9947) I would look at this sample [How to: Implement a Custom Criteria Language Operator](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument5206) and see if it does what you need.

Otherwise the suggestion is to add a Calculated Field then in your Script override the returned value of that Calculated Field see [Calculated Fields](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4813)

Hope this helps

Comment: Just adding onto that, the Implement a Custom Criteria Language Operator specifically show an example of creating a Function which returns a date in a different format, much like your first request. I have used Custom Functions in the past for XPO, but I must admit I haven't looked into ICustomFunctionOperatorFormattable and using it in the End User expression editor. I think it should work though based on what I am reading.